# How to find element in array which contains date?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array , each element contains date , cost, currency and name info:

```
a = [" 2017-04-25 2 USD Jogurt", " 2017-04-28 2 USD Milk", " 2019-04-25 2 USD 
Apple"]
```

I'm trying loop through an array  find and delete element with the date of 2019-04-25 , but I can't find  it

```
var indexes = [];
var index;

for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    if (a[index] === "2019-04-25") {
        rea.splice (index, 1);
    }
};
console.log(a);

>> (3) [" 2017-04-25 2 USD Jogurt", " 2017-04-28 2 USD Milk", " 2019-04-25 2 USD Apple"]
```

Comment: `if (a[index].indexOf('2019-04-25') >= 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) to check if string exists. Check below snippet.

```js
var a = [" 2017-04-25 2 USD Jogurt", " 2017-04-28 2 USD Milk", " 2019-04-25 2 USD Apple"] ;

for (var index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    if (a[index].includes("2019-04-25")) {
        a.splice (index, 1);
    }
};
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) & [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) methods like so:

```js
const array = [" 2017-04-25 2 USD Jogurt", " 2017-04-28 2 USD Milk", " 2019-04-25 2 USD Apple"];
const result = array.filter(d => !d.includes('2019-04-25')) // your date
console.log(result)
```